# How can I download a batch of images using one thread only?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

The app I'm working on, it has many table views and each cell has an image. Problem is that each image is done using a network request and a different thread, so the app ends up using many threads to asynchronously download all the images (in the cellForRowAtIndex method) which results in huge battery drain.

Is there a way I can download them using one thread only, perhaps one after the other? Is there a better way of handling this issue?

What about the framework Kingfisher?

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage to download multiple images asynchronously.

Comment: No need to do any extra code and handy work.

Comment: Kingfisher is for caching the downloaded images. It's unrelated to your question.

Comment: If you are using a single thread to synchronously download the images, it will take way more time to actually download them, so I'm pretty sure that will drain the battery even more. Just try downloading 100 images concurrently, then try to do it sequentially using `Data(contentsOf:)` (don't actually use this in a real project, since it's synchronous) and compare the battery usage.

Comment: So the images that create threads to download are actually equal to the number of cells displayed on the screen. Is it still correct to let them download asynchronously while using multiple threads at the same time even when the user is scrolling up and down?

Answer (score 3):

You could dispatch your network operation blocks onto an `NSOperationQueue` and set a lower value for `maxConcurrentOperationCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is actually a way, use Kingfisher 
here is my sample code for you:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                switch indexPath.section {
                case 0:
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BannerCell", for: indexPath) as! BannerCell

                    cell.loading.stopAnimating()

                    let urlString = banners[indexPath.row].image ?? ""
                    let url = URL(string: urlString)
                    cell.bannerPic.kf.indicatorType = .activity
                    cell.bannerPic.kf.setImage(with: url, completionHandler: {
                        (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            if let image = image{
                                if !(self.loaded[indexPath] ?? false){
                                    let aspectRatio = image.size.height/image.size.width

                                    let imageHeight = self.view.frame.width*aspectRatio
                                    tableView.beginUpdates()
                                    self.rowHeights[indexPath.row] = imageHeight
                                    tableView.endUpdates()
                                    self.loaded[indexPath] = true
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    })
                    cell.selectionStyle = .none
                    return cell
    }
```